# PHP LDAP number of locked out users

Tags: php, ldap

I am working on a script that can get the number of locked out users from Active directory. Not disabled, just current number of locked out users. Is this possible? I havent worked with fetching data from AD before so I'm asking you guys before I try.

Comment: What are you try?

Comment: I am trying to get the number of locked out users from active directory. It says so right in the queston.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for `(|(!(gosaVacationStop=*))(!(gosaVacationStop=0)))`.

That should fetch all users that have the attribute `lockoutTime` set and where it is not 0.

```
$result = ldap_search($con, '(&(samaccountname=*)(|(!(gosaVacationStop=*))(!(gosaVacationStop=0))))', '*');
echo ldap_count_entries($con, $result);
```

That should give you the number of locked accounts.

Answer (score -1):

LDAP unfortunately does not have session management. It only provides a directory service from which you can get data from. There are no such things as logged out users.

Maybe you can create a system, when a user logs in it saves the user/expiration in the database. If he log's out or the session/cookie gets destroyed it will be removed from the database.

Comment: I did not try to fetch logged out users... but locked out.. where the account has been locked. I want to display the amount of locked users in our intranet.

Comment: Maybe you can try this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795294/detect-if-an-active-directory-user-account-is-locked-using-ldap-in-python.