# Java: request all locked AD accounts

Tags: java, search, active-directory

I have code today that I can grab a single users AD info. What I am looking for is code that acts like Powershells Search-ADAccount -LockedOut

This is a snippet of what I have but it is not returning all Locked accounts.

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUri);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username@ourdomain.com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password";

try {
    DirContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null);
    SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
    searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=User)(lockoutTime>=1))";
    String searchBase = usersContainer;
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
    while (answer.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult result = (SearchResult) answer.next();
        adInfo = result.getAttributes();
    }

    ctx.close();
}
catch (NamingException e) {

}
```

I put this

```
(&(objectClass=User)(lockoutTime>=1))
```

line in there to see if it would just go and find all the locked accounts. I also tried

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(lockoutTime>=1))
```

but no luck.

So... I am at a stand still considering the lack of Java LDAP support so I turned to here to see if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if an Active Directory user account is locked using LDAP in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795294/detect-if-an-active-directory-user-account-is-locked-using-ldap-in-python)

Comment: Though the flagged duplicate is a Python question, but OP is using the same filter option of LDAP. It'd work for you.

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: No error actually it is just not returning the same data as Powershell. I am thinking that this is not doing a search since it only returns three users but it returns all their data and funny as they are not locked. 

I know I am doing something wrong here just not sure what lol.

I'll check out the other post in a few.