# PHP LDAP retrieve non default attribute/property "lockedOut"

Tags: php, ldap

Is there a way with the PHP LDAP extension to retrieve AD attributes/properties that are not returned by default?

Specifically, I am trying to retrieve the `lockedOut` property. This one is not retrieved by default when you use `ldap_get_attributes`. In PowerShell, you have to specify the property in order to retrieve it:

```
Get-AdUser -Identity foo -Properties LockedOut | Select LockedOut
```

But trying to specify the attribute the same way with PHP LDAP does not seem to work.

```php
$result = ldap_search($conn, $dn, "cn=foo", ["lockedOut"]);
if ($result === false) {
    // Handling error...
}
$count = ldap_count_entries($conn, $result);
if ($count !== 1) {
    // Handling error...
}
$entry = ldap_first_entry($conn, $result);

// This array does not contain the expected "lockedOut" attribute
$attr = ldap_get_attributes($conn, $entry);

// No array returned but false (error)
$value = ldap_get_values($conn, $entry, "lockedOut")
```

I feel like those non default properties are not retrievable with PHP LDAP (property != attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default attribute that does the job as a workaround: `lockoutTime`.
It seems to work this way:

- Account never locked: `lockoutTime = <not set>`
- Account locked in the past, but now unlocked: `lockoutTime = 0`
- Account locked: `lockoutTime = 1+`
  (= MS file time; amount of 100 nanoseconds since 1601-01-01 UTC)

The workaround code:

```php
$result = ldap_search($conn, $dn, "cn=foo", ["lockoutTime"]);
if ($result === false) {
    // Handling error...
}
$count = ldap_count_entries($conn, $result);
if ($count !== 1) {
    // Handling error...
}
$entry = ldap_first_entry($conn, $result);
$attr = ldap_get_attributes($conn, $entry);

$rawLockoutTime = $attr["lockouttime"] ?? null;
$isLockedOut = $rawLockoutTime !== null && $rawLockoutTime[0] !== "0";
```

[A reference about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11839756/7709086) on a post for the Python LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the `lockedOut` property but one commenter on PHP manual page [managed to fetch a few other non-standard or operational attributes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-attributes.php#78588) such as create and modify timestamps using the below method. Maybe, you can try adding `lockedOut` to that list of attributes and achieve some success with this method too?

```php
   $conn = $ds;
   $attrs = array( 'creatorsname', 'createtimestamp', 'modifiersname',
         'structuralObjectClass', 'entryUUID',  'modifytimestamp',
         'subschemaSubentry', 'hasSubordinates', '+' );
   $search = @ldap_read( $conn, $dn, '(objectClass=*)', $attrs, 0, 0, 0, $deref );
```

As another comment on the manual page suggests, you can also try looping through all entries until you find the `lockedOut`, this is another option:

```php
$entry = ldap_first_entry($ds, $sr);
write_attr($entry,$ds);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n_entries; $i++){
   $entry = ldap_next_entry($ds, $entry);
   write_attr($entry,$ds);
}
```

**Edit**

As discussed, also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795294/detect-if-an-active-directory-user-account-is-locked-using-ldap-in-python).

If you just want to know if the user is locked out, you can fetch `lockoutTime` instead and check its value. A zero or unset value for this means the user isn't locked out.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sadly the first method is unable to retrieve the `lockedOut` attribute. The second methods returns default attributes only (you forgot the `write_attr` function from the comment).

Comment: @kagmole Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795294/detect-if-an-active-directory-user-account-is-locked-using-ldap-in-python). If you just want to know if the user is locked out, you can fetch `lockoutTime` instead and check its value. A zero or unset value for this means the user isn't locked out.

Comment: I was actually going to post it as a workround answer, it seems to work well. If you want to post an answer you can do it. Otherwise I will post it.

Comment: No worries, go ahead and post it. I'll just edit my existing answer and make a note of it.